# Disposing method which returns Timer

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a method which returns System.Timers.Timer and then I use it along the code.
But MS Code Analysis gives a warning: CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope
Is it possible to manually Dispose Timer and therefore not to spot such a message?

Thank you!

Comment: CA2000 is notoriously inaccurate.  Flip the ignore bit if the warning is generated for the method itself instead of the method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `System.Timers.Timer` impliments `IDisposable` you can wrap your method call in a `using` statement to make sure `Dispose` is called.

```
using(var timer = myClass.TimerMethod())
{
  // Do the work here
}
```

Comment: if I wrap with using(){} the block of code inside the method which returns Timer, the object will be Disposed after method call so the Timer won't work.

Comment: You should be disposing of your timer after you've finished using it. With the using statement the timer is available to you until the using statement finishes, at which point it is disposed. How are you wanting to use your timer?

Comment: and my sugestion isn't to wrap the code inside the method returning the timer, it's to wrap the call to the method so that you can dispose of your timer when you're done.

Comment: the Timer is nested inside of the volatile object so it's quite complicated to wrap it.

Comment: and actually a call dispose manually but MS Code Analysis can't guarantee that Dispose is called in every execution path so the using statement is preferable to insure the safety but I wanna find another way if available.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Timers.Timer` implements `IDisposable` so just put it inside `using`:

```
using(var timer = MyMethodThatReturnsTimer())
{
}
```

If you cannot use `using` than just call `Dispose` yourself.

Comment: He says he returns the object. If he does what you say, there will be an error. I think he simply needs to call Dispose when done with the object.

Comment: yes. I use the returned object along the code. and the problem is in that I can't just wrap that block of code with using(){}.